# Emmet Commands Not Working When in Collaboration Session in VSCode

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, emmet

So I haven't touched anything with Emmet in VSCode, but I have tried using the commands (being that they are much faster than writing the code manually).

The Emmet commands work when I'm coding by myself or when I am hosting a collaboration session.

The Emmet commands don't work when I have joined someone in a collaboration session (meaning I am not the host of the collaboration session).

Any fix to where I can use Emmet commands when I have joined in a collaboration session? (Also I've tagged HTML, CSS, and JavaScript because those are some of the languages that Emmet works on)